# DEPRECATION WARNING after updating from Rails 5.0.0 to 5.0.0.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I updated my Rails app from 5.0.0 to 5.0.0.1 by running the command `bundle update rails`

Some commands that gives me this warning are:

```
rails s

rails db:migrate

rails db:seed

git push heroku
```

The full warning are:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Sprockets method `register_engine` is deprecated.
Please register a mime type using `register_mime_type` then
use `register_compressor` or `register_transformer`.
https://github.com/rails/sprockets/blob/master/guides/extending_sprockets.md#supporting-all-versions-of-sprockets-in-processors
 (called from block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie> at /home/jeramae/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.5/lib/sass/rails/railtie.rb:57)
DEPRECATION WARNING: Sprockets method `register_engine` is deprecated.
Please register a mime type using `register_mime_type` then
use `register_compressor` or `register_transformer`.
https://github.com/rails/sprockets/blob/master/guides/extending_sprockets.md#supporting-all-versions-of-sprockets-in-processors
 (called from block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie> at /home/jeramae/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.5/lib/sass/rails/railtie.rb:58)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade `sass-rails` by adding `gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0', '>= 5.0.6'` to `Gemfile` or modifying the existing line to this and run `bundle install --without production && bundle update` .